# batch file variables view client ip

Tags: batch-file, variables

Trying to record a user client IP for a remote session. Currently have a little batch file recording logon times, and hostname. Need to also include the client IP address;

Currently using this;

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment" /s > %temp%\IPINFO.txt
findstr /L ViewClient_IP_Address %temp%\IPINFO.txt > %temp%\IPRESULTS.txt
FOR /F “tokens=* delims= ” %%a in (%temp%\IPRESULTS.txt) do set IP=%%a
del %temp%\IPRESULTS.txt
set IP=%IP%
echo Login ,%Date%,%Time%,%computername%,%clientname%,%IP% >> Y:\%username%.csv
```

The registry key viewclient_ip_Address has the information I need, but the registry folder it sits within changes name each time so I'm having to export the whole directory and then filter for the key itself.

I just need to add the information from that IPRESULTS.txt into my end .csv file but struggling with writing it up.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? *(The [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) runs the command and parses it's output in memory)*

```bat
For /F "EOL=HTokens=2*" %%H In ('^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "HKCU\Volatile Environment" /V ViewClient_IP_Address 2^>NUL^"')Do Set "IP=%%~I"
```

To find out more about how to use reg.exe with query, open up a Command Prompt window and enter `reg query /?`

If, as you've stated in your question, the required value and data is located under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment` but within a variable/unknown, subkey name, the help information should show you that you can use the `/F` option to locate your known value name, `ViewClient_IP_Address`, if you specify that the search is to locate a value using `/V`, it should retrieve the line you need.

For example, at the Command Prompt:

```bat
Reg Query "HKCU\Volatile Environment" /S /F "ViewClient_IP_Address" /V
```

Returns:

> ```bat
> C:\Users\smith_ll>Reg Query "HKCU\Volatile Environment" /S /F "ViewClient_IP_Add
> ress" /V
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment\UnknownSubKey
>     ViewClient_IP_Address    REG_SZ    192.168.1.15
>
> End of search: 1 match(es) found.
> ```

You can then put that command into your [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop), and pass its output through find.exe to isolate the line you need to parse. The underscore, for instance, looks unique to just the line you need. As we're already excluding any line beginning with `H` ,*(with `EOL=H`)*, it will not match the `End of search: 1 match(es) found.` line:

Example:

```bat
For /F "EOL=HTokens=2*" %%H In ('^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "HKCU\Volatile Environment" /S /F "ViewClient_IP_Address" /V 2^>NUL^|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" "_"^"')Do @Set "IP=%%~I"
```

If you don't like the super long line, you can split into more using the caret:

```bat
For /F "EOL=HTokens=2*" %%H In ('^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query^
 "HKCU\Volatile Environment" /S /F "ViewClient_IP_Address" /V 2^>NUL^
 ^|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" "_"^"')Do @Set "IP=%%~I"
```

Comment: Brill! Thanks @compo. Added the line you suggested in the example has got the outcome I needed. Much appreciated.